# CSS: Help with aligning div (expand - collapse) boxes next to each other

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am having some trouble with aligning two div boxes next to each other;. Or more correctly, I have aligned my two “head” boxes next to each other but my problem is that I am using them as a expand-collapse container and those boxes will not align correctly.

I am posting the entire code beneath and would be grateful if someone had a solution to this problem, which probably is not that difficult. And another problem is, that when I expand the hidden area the two boxes "resets" and again stand under each other.

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- Panel Slider for Contact -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <!-- Expand Collapse -->
    <script type="text/javascript">$(function(){
$("#mostrar1").click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();
                $("#caja1").slideToggle();
                });

$("#caja1 a").click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();
                $("#caja1").slideUp();
                });
$("#mostrar2").click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();
                $("#caja2").slideToggle();
                });

$("#caja2 a").click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();
                $("#caja2").slideUp();
                });
}); </script> 

<style type="text/css">
.slide-out-div {
       padding: 20px;
       width: 250px;
       background: #031F2F;
       margin: 0px;

    }

            #caja1 {
            width:30%;
            display: none;
            padding:5px;
            border:2px solid #FFFFFF;
            background-color:#99a8ff;
            }

            #mostrar1{
            display:block;
            width:30%;
            padding:5px;
            border:2px solid #FFFFFF;
            background-color:#0C415F;
            float: left;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            }           

            #caja2 {
            width:30%;
            display: none;
            padding:5px;
            border:2px solid #FFFFFF;
            background-color:#99a8ff;
            }

            #mostrar2{
            display:block;
            width:30%;
            padding:5px;
            border:2px solid #FFFFFF;
            background-color:#0C415F;
            float: left;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            }           
            }   

</style>
</head>
<body>

        <a href="#" id="mostrar1">Private</a><div style="display: none;" id="caja1"><a href="#" class="close">[x]</a><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren</p></div><a href="#" id="mostrar2">Erhverv</a><div style="display: none;" id="caja2"><a href="#" class="close">[x]</a><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren</p></div>        
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks
Mestika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me on Firefox 3.7a. Two things changed: added a doctype and wrapped each column in a wrapper. Wrapper class could probably be named something more semantic, that's up to you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- Panel Slider for Contact -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <!-- Expand Collapse -->
    <script type="text/javascript">$(function(){
$("#mostrar1").click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();
                $("#caja1").slideToggle();
                });

$("#caja1 a").click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();
                $("#caja1").slideUp();
                });
$("#mostrar2").click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();
                $("#caja2").slideToggle();
                });

$("#caja2 a").click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();
                $("#caja2").slideUp();
                });
}); </script>

<style type="text/css">
.wrapper {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
.slide-out-div {
       padding: 20px;
       width: 250px;
       background: #031F2F;
       margin: 0px;
    }

            #caja1 {
            display: none;
            padding:5px;
            border:2px solid #FFFFFF;
            background-color:#99a8ff;
            }

            #mostrar1{
            display:block;
            padding:5px;
            border:2px solid #FFFFFF;
            background-color:#0C415F;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            }

            #caja2 {
            display: none;
            padding:5px;
            border:2px solid #FFFFFF;
            background-color:#99a8ff;
            }

            #mostrar2{
            display:block;
            padding:5px;
            border:2px solid #FFFFFF;
            background-color:#0C415F;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<a href="#" id="mostrar1">Private</a><div style="display: none;" id="caja1"><a href="#" class="close">[x]</a><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren</p></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
<a href="#" id="mostrar2">Erhverv</a><div style="display: none;" id="caja2"><a href="#" class="close">[x]</a><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren</p></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: chrome also approves this change.